# Google App Engine - Extended European Offering

Tags: google-app-engine

I would like to move my App Engine app to the EU. I signed up for the Google App Engine - Extended European Offering using a Google Docs form a long time ago but nothing happens. Has anyone gotten a word back from Google regarding this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you get automatically notified or not for these, but check in appengine.google.com and try to create an application. If the European offering got extended to you, you will have a choice when you create your App on where you want it hosted.

One thing that you cannot do though, is move an already created App to the EU. You need to re upload your app, make sure you use the [backup & restore](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/datastoreadmin) from datastore to keep your data, make sure you're ready to change your domain redirects, etc.

Comment: I don't find the EU option when I try to create a new application via appengine.google.com. However, if I create a new App Engine application via console.developers.google.com I do get the EU option. But back in appengine.google.com I can not verify that it is a EU application.

Comment: @Carl they must've changed it recently then. Create it as a EU in console.developers.google.com. appengine.google.com is their older console, they're rolling it out